# Transform table into column

Tags: excel

I am trying to get the results of a basketball season. This is the table I have with random values:

[image]

What I want is transform that into something like this:

[image]

I am currently using this formula `=A19 & " - " & C18` and in this case the results I get from it is:

[image]

And then I just copy the results and past it as Transpose.

I don't know if I was clear, something you need tell me and I will update the question.

Comment: It would be easier if you pasted that as a table so anyone wanting to test it could paste into their own file. You probably need Index and Match.

Comment: Maybe this could work: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2773-excel-convert-matrix-to-list.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following formulas (edited to make formulas work from the second row) -

For the first team:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$E$1;1;INT((ROW()+2)/(ROWS($A$2:$A$5))))
```

For the second team:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$5;ROW()-1-ROWS($A$2:$A$5)*INT((ROW()-2)/ROWS($A$2:$A$5));1)
```

For result:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$E$5;MATCH(INDEX($A$2:$A$5;ROW()-1-ROWS($A$2:$A$5)*INT((ROW()-2)/ROWS($A$2:$A$5));1);$A$2:$A$5;0);MATCH(INDEX($B$1:$E$1;1;INT((ROW()+2)/(ROWS($A$2:$A$5))));$B$1:$E$1;0))
```

The tournament table must be symmetrical.

If the first two formulas are in separate columns (as in my example), in the third formula, the inner `INDEX (...)` functions can be replaced by a reference to the corresponding column.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It solved my problem. Did some changes, but I was able to do it.